# Laravel 8 - creating a membership table during user registration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am currently working on a user-membership system. I have a user and usermeta tables which get created during registration. I have created membership table and I want to add membership detail (such as membership number, membership level and membership status) to it during user registration, like I did with usermetas. But I keep getting an error "local.INFO: timeout-or-duplicate".

```
//membership model
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Enums\MembershipStatus;

class Membership extends Model
{
    //use SoftDeletes;
    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'membership',
        'membership_no',
        'status',
        'start_date',
        'expiring_date'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'start_date' => 'datetime',
        'expiring_date' => 'datetime',
        'deleted_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}

//user model
class User extends Authenticatable {
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'username',
        'email',
        'password',
        'role',
        'status',
        'refer',
        '2fa',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];
    protected $casts = [
        'last_login' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function user_metas() {
        return $this->hasMany(UserMeta::class);
    }

    public function membership() {
        return $this->hasOne(Membership::class);
    }
}

public function register(RegistrationRequest $request) {
        if (has_recaptcha()) {
            RecaptchaService::verify($request);
        }

        $emailMetaCount = $this->settingsService->emailMetaCount($request->email);

        if ($emailMetaCount > 0) {
            throw ValidationException::withMessages(['email' => __("The chosen email is already registered with us. Please use a different email address.")]);
        }

        DB::beginTransaction();
        try {
            $data = array_map('strip_tags_map', $request->only('name', 'confirmation')) + $request->all();
            $newUser = $this->auth->createUser($data);

            if (! $newUser) {
                throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                    'invalid' => __('An error occurred during registration, please try again later. If the issues continues, contact us.')
                ]);
            }

            if (User::count() > 1 && mandatory_verify()) {
                ProcessEmail::dispatch('users-confirm-email', $newUser);
            }

            DB::commit();

            return view('auth.checkout', compact('newUser'));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            DB::rollBack();
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'invalid' => __('Sorry, due to technical issues, registration failed. Please try again after sometimes or contact us.')
            ]);
        }
    }

//createuser in authservice
    public function createUser($data, $autoVerified = false) {
        $data['username'] = $this->generateUniqueUsername(first_word($data['name']));
        $data['status'] = ($autoVerified) ? UserStatus::ACTIVE : UserStatus::INACTIVE;
        $data['password'] = Hash::make($data['password']);
        $data['role'] = (isset($data['role'])) ? $data['role'] : Roles::USER;

        if ($data['role'] == Roles::USER && $this->referralService->getReferMeta()) {
            $data['refer'] = json_encode($this->referralService->getReferMeta());
        }

        $user = new User();
        $user->fill($data);
        $user->save();
        $this->saveDefaultUserMeta($user, $data['registration_method'] ?? null, $data);

        Membership::create([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'membership' => $data['membership_level'],
            'membership_no' => generate_unique_no(16),
            'status' => UserStatus::INACTIVE,
            'start_date' => Carbon::now(),
            'expiring_date' => Carbon::now()->addYear()
        ]);

        $verifyToken = $this->createVerifyToken($user);
        if ($autoVerified) {
            $verifyToken->verify = Carbon::now();
            $verifyToken->save();

            if (referral_system() && !empty($user->refer)) {
                $this->referralService->createReferral($user);
            }

            $this->saveEmailVerificationMeta($user);
        }

        return $user;
    }
```

If I remove the membersahip insert code, everything works as expected. I have also tried this

```
$membershipData = [
     'user_id' => $user->id,
     'membership' => $data['membership_level'],
     'membership_no' => generate_unique_no(16),
     'status' => UserStatus::INACTIVE,
     'start_date' => Carbon::now(),
     'expiring_date' => Carbon::now()->addYear()
 ];
 $membership = new Membership();
 $membership->fill($membershipData);
 $membership->save();
```

Nothing works

Comment: The membership table is already created. I want to add membership detail (such as membership number and membership level, membership status) for each user at registration to the membership table.

Comment: Provide detail info about error and show your migration

Comment: You pasted this: `local.INFO` which means it comes from your log file. Just post the entire error message with the stack trace, in your original question please

Answer (score 1):

Sorry all, I was the forgetful, silly one. After @underDog comment, I took another look into the catch part of the `try{}..catch{}` and echo the `exception $e` with `$e->getMessage()` to see what is actually inside of it. I discovered that I had named my Membership table `membership` instead of `memberships` during migration.

Lesson from this, always ensure your table is the plural version of your model; e.g Model.php owns models table. Thanks